# create a batch which runs a series of sqlcmds which first selects a list of unique names, then selects data related to each of those and output to csv

Tags: sql, sql-server, batch-file

I wrote a batch file to execute a bunch of repeated lines of the following structure:

```
sqlcmd "select somedata from table where table.attribute is like 'name'" > name_date.csv
```

The where is filtering on the attribute which determines what data is related to a specific named piece of hardware. I then output to file and then repeat the line for the rest of the names. _date is set from a variable in the batch file. The DBMS is SQL server.

That works well and writes out all the files fine, which is already a time saver, but if I was to use that batch file on another customers database to extract the same data for their hardware, I’d have to manually update each repeat of the above command in the batch with their list of unique names. The hardware names could be anywhere from a couple to hundreds total. What I’d like to do is build on it so it is useful for any list of those names without manual intervention.

I can isolate that unique list of names  by using select distinct, but then making some kind of for each loop which substitutes each of those unique values in turn into the sqlcmd and outputs each to a separate file, all within the same batch file so the user just has to run it without intervention, is beyond me.

Summary: I want to create a batch file which runs a series of sqlcmds which first selects a list of unique names, then for each of those names selects certain data relating to them and printing out to a csv File with that name, then repeats for the next unique name etc

Thank you for your time, I appreciate any tips and advice for further learning.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to handle this, depending on details of your situation and how automated you want to get. Since the data originates in a DB, it is straightforward to write a SQL query that generates the lines of your batch file.

In the solution below, the inner select statement selects [attribute] from [table], concatenating the rest of your command around it. This provides each line (one line per row returned, i.e. one line per attribute name). The STRING_AGG in the outer select statement then combines the multiple rows (lines) together, with a linefeed to separate each line.

```
declare @bat nvarchar(max);    
select @bat = STRING_AGG(lines.oneLine, char(10))
from (
  select 'sqlcmd "select somedata from table where attribute like ''' +
    [attribute] + '''" > ' +
    [attribute] + '_date.csv' as oneLine
  from [table]
  where [attribute] is not null
  group by [attribute]
) as lines;
```

From here, just copy & paste the results into your batch file. Or get creative and use xp_cmdshell to write @bat out to the file system. If you bundle all this into one script, you could create a BAT file that runs the script, which generates the BAT file.